# Use of Unassigned Local Variable with Graphics.Drawing

Tags: c#, graphics, compiler-errors, drawing

So I'm trying to write a program that draws a circle by drawing a line every 1 degree and changes color by incrementing through RGB (Started by Random).

Here is the code that I have so far

```
public static void drawCircle(int iRandR, int iRandG, int iRandB)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 359; ++x)
    {
        double dXAngle = 0;
        double dYAngle = 0;
        dXAngle = 300 + Math.Cos(x) + 200;
        dYAngle = 300 + Math.Sin(x) + 200;
        Pen pPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, iRandR, iRandG, iRandB));
        Graphics gDraw;
        int iXAngle = Convert.ToInt32(dXAngle);
        int iYAngle = Convert.ToInt32(dYAngle);
        gDraw.DrawLine(pPen, 300, 300, iXAngle, iYAngle); //Error called here
    }

}
private void drawCircleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int genRandR = 0;
    int genRandG = 0;
    int genRandB = 0;
    Random rRand = new Random();
    genRandR = rRand.Next(0, 255);
    genRandG = rRand.Next(0, 255);
    genRandB = rRand.Next(0, 255);
    drawCircle(genRandR, genRandG, genRandB);
    drawCircleButton.Hide();
}
```

The only problem is that the compiler has a problem with the above line and it throws "Use of unassigned local variable 'gDraw'" I did some googling and a lot of other examples looked like mine but I can't figure out why mine was throwing this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `gDraw` (`Graphics` to be specific) is a reference type. It doesn't have a default value. Thus, needs to be initialized (using the `new` keyword maybe?)

Comment: What are you drawing to? A WinForms control? A `Bitmap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the desired [`Graphics` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) as a parameter from somewhere. The `Graphics` class, as explained on MSDN, encapsulates a GDI+ drawing surface. It's used to abstract various drawing operations to different display devices (your screen, a bitmap, metafile, or even printing).

```
public static void DrawCircle(Graphics gDraw, int iRandR, int iRandG, int iRandB)
{
    ...
}
```

You are probably calling it from a `Paint` event handler, or something similar, where you have access to the `Graphics` object you want to draw to. I.e.:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs p)
{
     var graphics = p.Graphics;
     DrawCircle(graphics, ...);
}
```

Comment: I've done this a million times and some how I forgot this... Worked perfectly thanks so much!

Comment: On second look, it looks like OnPaint runs automatically without me calling it, odd.

Comment: @Cistoran: `OnPaint` is called on the GUI thread when the control is about to be drawn. Specifically, when it is invalidated, Windows will send a paint message to the form, which will invoke the `OnPaint` method. You don't need to (and shouldn't) call it, you usually override it to place your own drawing logic inside. If you don't do this, base `Control.OnPaint` method is called and your control (or `UserControl`, or `Form`) gets its default look, after which it fires the `Paint` event.